# Woocommerce 'remove product' remove X and replace with an image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, function

Im trying to replace a cross with an image to delete products but i can't make it work, it says that the path invalid.

here's the JS:

```
function replaceCross($){
// search the Woocommerce object
var link    = $(".woocommerce .product-remove a");
var can     = $('<img id="trashcan">');
var dir     = "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>";

can.attr("src", +dir+ "/images/garbage.png");
can.appendTo(".woocommerce .product-remove");
```

}

and the HTML:

```
<tr class="woocommerce-cart-form__cart-item cart_item">
    <td class="product-remove">
        <a href="#" class="remove" aria-label="Dit artikel verwijderen" data-product_id="627" data-product_sku="MUDD &amp; WATER dr Alice white leaf-XS">×</a>
        <img id="trashcan" src="NaN/images/garbage.png">
    </td>
</tr>
```

and i'm running a localize script in the functions.php like:

```
function custom_script(){
wp_enqueue_script( 'general-script' ,STYLE_WEB_ROOT . '/js/script.js', array('jquery'), '1.0' , true );

$script_data = array(
    'image_path' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/'
);
wp_localize_script(
    'custom_script',
    'cs_custom',
    $script_data
);
```

}

I'm still a learner in jQuery and PHP so be gentle please c:

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

As of the day, I am writing this, one of the easiest ways of doing this is to override the `cart.php` file in your theme on `woocommerce/cart/cart.php`. Copy the contents of `template/cart/cart.php` from woocommerce plugin folder into your theme on `woocommerce/cart/cart.php`.

Make changes to the following section by removing `&times` to anything you wish.

```
<td class="product-remove">
    <?php
        echo apply_filters( // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped
            'woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link',
            sprintf(
                '<a href="%s" class="remove" aria-label="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s"><i class="fa fa-trash-alt"></i></a>',
                esc_url( wc_get_cart_remove_url( $cart_item_key ) ),
                esc_html__( 'Remove this item', 'woocommerce' ),
                esc_attr( $product_id ),
                esc_attr( $_product->get_sku() )
            ),
            $cart_item_key
        );
    ?>
</td>
```

Answer (score -1):

Changing that icon in JavaScript is a huge mistake. Basically what you would be doing is loading the old icon and then send a script to the client to change it.

The correct solution is to replace it in WordPress using CSS, so you actually send the new icon style from the beginning. You can find a comprehensive tutorial on how to change that icon by a simple google search: https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-change-remove-item-icon-cart/

The tutorial shows how to modify the icon using font awesome, but you can do it with your own image (an avoid loading the entire font-awesome library just for that icon) doing:

```
.woocommerce a.remove:before{
   content: "";
   background-image: url(path-to-your-image.png);
}
```